How to deploy express app which located in subfolder?
I have no problem If I try to deploy my app which located in root folder. But if I move my app to /node and try again I receive a 404 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/public/pages/index/index.html'
Vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [ {"src": "index.js", "use": "@vercel/node"} ],
    "rewrites": [ {"source": "/", "destination": "index.js"} ]
}

Index.js
import express from "express";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { router } from "./src/routes/index.route.js";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(resolve(resolve("public"))));
app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});

Index.routes.js
import { Router } from "express";
import { resolve } from "path";

const router = Router();
const __dirname = resolve();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, "public", "pages", "index", "index.html"));
});

export { router };

Structure of my folders
.git
node/
    node_modules/
    public/
      pages/
        index/
            index.html
    src/
      routes/
        index.route.js
    index.js
    package.json
    vercel.json

Also I tried config my vercel.json like than
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [ 
      {"src": "index.js", "use": "@vercel/node"},
      {"src": "public/**", "use": "@vercel/static"} 
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {"source": "/", "destination": "index.js"} ]
}

After this in Vercel -> Current deploy -> Source -> Output was a folder public with my static files, but I still get an 404 error.
I also write my Root Directory in Project Setting in Vercel. In my case node
I think problem in my index.route.js or where I configure my static files
app.use(express.static(resolve(resolve("public"))));

May be someone have this problem?
